# Using ADB to Launch Web Page With Multiple Querystring Parameters

Tags: c#, android, .net, adb, madbee

I'm trying to launch a web page inside a vitual android device. The address of the page takes multiple querystring parameters. For some reason when passing the url in all parameters after the first & are missing (including the &).

I have a very simple C# WinForm app to test this with. I am using MadBee NuGet package to send the commands to the android VM.

When I send the command I see the url loaded but as I described, it is missing the parameters that come after he first &

Below is a snippet of the code I am calling:

```
command = "am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d http://w18299:8009/Assignment/manage?assigner=57072352&unitID=6443&secret=asdasdasdasdasd&assignee=57072352";
ConsoleOutputReceiver creciever = new ConsoleOutputReceiver();
device.ExecuteShellCommand(command, creciever);
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why the parameters would not make it across to Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameters "make it across to Android" just fine. What you failed to realize is that your command is getting parsed by the Android `shell` on the device side and `&` has a special meaning for it. To stop the `shell` from treating `&` as special symbol use quotes like this:

```
command = "am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d 'http://w18299:8009/Assignment/manage?assigner=57072352&unitID=6443&secret=asdasdasdasdasd&assignee=57072352'";
```